# ListView Click and Drag Select

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

With `ListView` in `view = Detail` mode, you can only click and drag select in the blank space, and not when you are on text.

How do you enable click and drag select when the user click on the text and drag?

Comment: That's just how the control works.  "Lasso" selection only works when you click on a non-item area.  When you click on an item it doesn't have to guess what you're trying to select, it must be the item.  Use the Control or Shift key while clicking to select more than one item.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an empty, very narrow (e.g. 10 px) column as the first column. That will look like row header column. Users can use that for drag & drop. You can also custom paint the background of the column (to gray for instance) to give looks of a row header.